# Python: Why is my POST requests not working?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to uses requests.post to submit a form on a page, but all it does is go to the page the form is on.

http://www.gwinnettcountysheriff.com/smartwebclient/

```
def gwinnett_search(last, first, middle, booked):
    headers = {'Content-type': "application/json",'accept':'application/json'}
    payload = {'LastName': last, 'FirstName': first, 'MiddleName': middle, 'BeginBookDate': booked}
    print("Gwinnett County Detention Center")
    r = requests.post("http://www.gwinnettcountysheriff.com/smartwebclient/", json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.headers)
#    print(r.text)

gwinnett_search(last, first, middle, option)
```

When I run the code it returns the following( along with the page w/ the form i'm submitting POST to).

```
Gwinnett County Detention Center
200
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Sun, 31 Mar 2019 01:07:32 GMT', 'Content-Length': '64441'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I read someone suggesting troubleshooting by adding:

```
print(r.json())
```

which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Sun, 31 Mar 2019 01:15:57 GMT', 'Content-Length': '64434'}
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/inmate_search/inmate_search.py", line 58, in <module>
    gwinnett_search(last, first, middle, option, booked)
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/inmate_search/inmate_search.py", line 56, in gwinnett_search
    print(r.json())
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/inmate_search/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It might also be worth noting that the url on this site doesn't change when you use the search form. Is there some problem with JSON im not seeing, or should I just use selenium?

Edit: I'm adding this code as requested.

```
last = input("Last Name:")
first = input("First Name: ")
middle = input("Middle Name: ")
booked = input("Booking Date(00/00/0000): ")

def options():
    select = input("Enter 1 for In Custody or 2 for Inquiry:")
    if select == "1":
        select = "In+Custody"
    elif select == "2":
        select = "Inquiry"
    else:
        print("Error. That was not an option")
        options()
    return select

option = options()
```

Comment: What does `print(r.text)` show?

Comment: What are `last`, `first`, `middle` and `option`?

Comment: print(r.text) shows the page that the form i'm try to submit is one. So its basically as if it was request.get instead of .post.

Comment: @gmds i'll ad the code for that.

Answer (score 3):

you aren't doing anything wrong. I went to check the server and found that the server is set up such that the POST request returns HTML. However, it is not the exact same HTML as the original page, as this returned HTML only contains information about the inmate(s) that you were searching for.

If you want to extract the information about the inmates from this HTML, I'd suggest using something like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is a HTML parser and will allow you to extract whatever information you want.

Comment: thanks for the help. That makes sense, but the response I got from was the same as original(which has similar tables). I originally had beautifulsoup in the script; then i noticed the names were from the original page. How can I get the POST response you mentioned?

Comment: Hi there, sorry, went to check again and found that indeed it is the same as the original page. My apologies for not checking properly. I went to do some further inspection and found that the loading of the searched inmates is done via javascript; in this case, using Selenium, a browser automation tool, would be needed to get it to work.

Comment: I was starting to think I might have to use selenium. The url doesn't change when you search so that's probably my only choice.